# Can I install Windows 7 after Installing Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, system-installation

I already installed Ubuntu ;
I'm attempting to install Windows 7 but I cant because my hard drive is a  different file system format.

### Steps I've Tried

1. I attempted to format part of my disk to make room for Windows 7, but on the list of partitions in the Ubuntu Installer I can't change the partition type to Primary.  As such it's impossible to install Windows 7.
2. I also tried to run my Windows 7 ISO image using Ubuntu

Since I can't figure out the proper install order, I thought I'd start by asking here.  I also have 3 extra hard drives, so if anyone can help I'd appreciate it.  Is there any way for efficiency sake to have Windows 7 one click away, say for example to open Ubuntu and run the Windows 7 installer on a different disk?

Is it possible to do it this way, if not what is the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you even understand what you mean when you wrote "file system format"? Do you mean you installed in BIOS or UEFI mode? Or did you format the whole drive with Ubuntu to `ext4`? Well, in short: it's usually easier to install Windows 7 first, and then install Ubuntu.

Then the rest is not really to-the-point content per see but I assume if you really need help it's the next best thing you can read for yourself get.

Please take a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community

It is advisable to read the first three bullet points under *Help Topics*, which are:

- [Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)
- [SwitchingToUbuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu)
- [DrivesAndPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DrivesAndPartitions)

And then this is *the* article which you should read in whole:

- [*WindowsDualBoot* aka installing both Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Do *not* underestimate the info behind the links. :)

Then, directly related to the steps you've tried:

- Is it possible for you to delete Ubuntu and make a backup of your data (documents, pictures... whatnot)?

> Is there any way for efficiency sake to have Windows 7 one click away, say for example to open Ubuntu and run the Windows 7 installer on a different disk?

I don't know what that means. I don't think you can run the Win 7 installer from Linux. Or you'd be a highly experienced user if you manage to do that.